# Typing linked network locations without dialog in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In outlook, I used to be able to type:

```
<Z:\Location one\Test>
```

And by adding the < and > it'd automatically turn the whole thing into a link.  Otherwise it'd just create a link to "Z:\Location".
But now it doesn't even turn it into a link at all either typing it normally or with the <>.  The closest thing I've found is ctrl+k brings up the URL dialog, but I'd prefer a way that doesn't involve a dialog.

I double checked my

File->Options->Mail->Compose Message->Editor Options->Autocorrect Options->Autoformat-> Replace... Internet and network paths with hyperlinks

is correctly checked.  URLs like https://www.google.com do get replaced, but not network locations. Any ideas how to get it to replace network locations with URLs?

Comment: Network path example will be \\locations\share which can be automatically turned to link. <Z:\Location one\Test> seems to be a local path.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb527e4b-87cb-42f0-8965-a78cb0ba3204/what-is-the-network-path?forum=winforms

Comment: @Perry If I use ctrl+k and type in the local path into the address location, it is smart enough to link the full network path while displaying the text of the local path (even though I didn't otherwise specify any "text to display").  Which is the behavior I'd like for the autoformat, but maybe this smart feature is never something autoformat did so for reasons of not wanting people to accidentally send dead links they've just disabled the autoformat for local paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix your link with file:// like this:

```
file://Z:\Location one\Tes
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: That works, but doesn't have the smart behavior of the URL dialog where it replaces the local name with a network path, but I don't think that was something the <> did either back when it worked.  I guess you can't win them all and this certainly does do what I asked for.